# How can I save query results into a new column and save it in the table with SQL Oracle Live?

Tags: sql, oracle, live

This is the query:

```
SELECT ROUND(column_1,0) as new_column_to_save
FROM table_to_save_to
```

Thank you

Comment: insert into .. select

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna insert it into a new table :

```
INSERT INTO NEWTableName ( colName)
SELECT ROUND(column_1,0) as new_column_to_save
FROM table_to_save_to
```

If you want to update a column within the same table

```
UPDATE table_to_save_to
   SET new_column_to_save = ROUND(column_1,0)
FROM table_to_save_to
```